# Analytical solution of an inhomogeneous second-order PDE

Tags: parabolic-pde

I would be thankful to anyone who can present an analytical solution to the following inhomogeneous PDE equation:

$$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}= \alpha\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x^2}}-ku$$

$$u(0,t) = 0$$

$$u(1,t) = M_R$$

$$u(x,0) = x*f(x)$$

where k, $\alpha$ and $M_R$ are constants and k>0.

Comment: In $u(x, 0) = x \ast f(x)$ does $x \ast f(x)$  mean $x \times f(x)$ or the convolution of $x$ and $f(x)$?

Comment: it means $x \times f(x)$

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!